# How can I design a Python function to print a matrix with only the forward diagonal elements set to True?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print an n*n matrix with only the forward diagonal elements set to True and the rest to False.

Here is my code:

```
def func(n):
    dp = [[False]*n]*n
    for i in range(n):
        dp[i][i] = True
    print(dp)
```

I'm baffled as to why the True values are spreading through the entire matrix instead of remaining confined to the cells where i=j.

**Desired output for n=5:**

```
True False False False False
False True False False False
False False True False False
False False False True False
False False False False True
```

**Current output for n=5:**

```
True True True True True
True True True True True
True True True True True
True True True True True
True True True True True
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that multiplying with `*` does not create new object, as @TobyPetty mentioned.

The way to fix would be:

```
def func(n):
    dp = [[[False] for i in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        dp[i][i] = True
    print(dp)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the shorthand you're using to create lists actually just creates copies of the same list. You can check this with the `id` function:

```
n = 5
dp = [[False]*n]*n
print([id(x) for x in dp])
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that saved my life! Will accept when I can

Comment: Accepted the other answer because was more complete, yours was enough for me to figure it out though so thanks :)